# SQL Server support for international chars such as c with cedilla

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a website where users can register. The registration information is stored in SQL Server. A user registered recently and the username included a "c with cedilla" in other words `François`

This is stored in SQL Server 2008R2 in a `nvarchar` column with a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

When I look at the data in SSMS, it looks like this: `FranÃ§ois`

I use a stored procedure to check the username/password, and it is failing as the two are not the same.

So I am not sure what I need to do here. Is there a different collation that I should use? Why is it getting altered if I am using an `nvarchar` column?

Greg

Comment: use UTF-8 for anything dealing with multi-language text. using any SPECIFIC other language set will just cause major pain later on.

Comment: First of all, for Unicode columns (`nvarchar`), the collation is irrelevant (other than for sorting data) - the code page for `nvarchar` is always 16-bit UTF-16 (2 bytes for each character). Secondly: can you show us how you insert the data into SQL Server? If you're using a literal SQL statement, you must use the `N'.....'` prefix to show it's a Unicode string.

Comment: @MarcB: SQL Server doesn't really support UTF-8 - it's using either a non-Unicode encoding (dependent on the collation), or the UTF-16 Unicode code page for `nvarchar` columns

Comment: @marc_s: Your correct, it's not a Sql Server issue - I was able to change the value to use the cedilla and SSMS stored it correctly and let the person log on.  So the issue is with getting the data into the database correctly.